# Como usar Json em um html

Tags: javascript, html, json

E ae pessoal? sou novo aqui, poderiam me ajudar...está retornando "NaN"!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr1 = JSON.parse(response);
    var out = "<h1>";
    out += arr1.Name + arr1.City + arr1.Country;
    out += "</h1>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que está retornando NaN?

Comment: Coloca o retorno `json`.

Comment: A minha ideia era retornar apenas retornar o índice 1 do array ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa acessar cada indice do seu objeto json. você pode fazer isso com um simples for. depois é só fazer um innerHTML quando terminar, é recomendado por questão de desempenho nao manipular o DOM dentro do for, então apenas concatene, fiz um exemplo fazendo a impressão de uma lista.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
  var arr1 = JSON.parse(response);
  var out = "<ul>";
  for (i in arr1) {
    out += "<li> Nome: " + arr1[i]['Name'] + " City: " + arr1[i]['City'] + " Country: " + arr1[i]['County'] + "</li>";
  }
  out += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>
```

Agora se for acessar apenas o primeiro indice basta  fazer assim:

```
function myFunction(response) {
  var arr1 = JSON.parse(response);
  var out = "<ul>";
  out += "<li> Nome: " + arr1[0]['Name'] + " City: " + arr1[0]['City'] + " Country: " + arr1[0]['County'] + "</li>"; // [0] acessa o primeiro indice.
  out += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: A minha ideia era retornar apenas retornar o índice 1 do array .... por isso coloquei "arr1" (o "1" queria q fosse o índice), então ele só reconhece se for um FOR ?

Comment: @Johnner Não é problema, nem precisa de usar for, mas para que retornar tantos valores se você deseja utilizar apenas o primeiro? vou reeditar adicionando a forma de pegar apenas o primeiro.

Comment: Muito obrigado você me ajudou muito!! era apenas para colocar o 1 entre colchetes ... VLW

Answer (score 4):

Sua variável `arr1`é uma lista de objetos e não apenas um objeto, para acessá-la você precisa informar o `índice` de cada objeto na lista.

Utilize o `for`para acessar todos os itens dessa lista, dentro do `for` a variável `i` será o índice de cada objeto.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
  var arr1 = JSON.parse(response);
  var out = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    out += "<p>";
    out += arr1[i].Name + " - " + arr1[i].City + " - " + arr1[i].Country;
    out += "</p>";
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

É preciso usar o `for` para acessar os itens do *array()*.

```
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    out += arr1[i].Name + ' - ' + arr1[i].City + ' - ' + arr1[i].Country;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ou utilize o conceito do foreach:

```
for (var i in arr1) {
   out += "<p> " + arr1[i].Name + " - " + arr1[i].City + " - " + arr1[i].Country + " </p>";
}
```